# turn multidimensional array to normal

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
       (
         [0] => Array
            (
                [text] => 2
            )

         [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => 3
                    )

            )

         [2] => Array
            (
                [text] => 4
            )

     )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [text] => 5
    )

)
```

i dont know number of dimensions, there can be many of them. Also key of target subarrays can be not 'text', but its always text key, not numerical. How do i turn this array into array like this?

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [text] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [text] => 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [text] => 3
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [text] => 4
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [text] => 5
    )

)
```

UPDATE: Okay, i didnt explain, and didnt understand whole question by myself. The thing is that array is formed by recursion i have one function:

```
public static function goToAction($action)
{
    $actions = array();
    $logic = file_get_contents('../../logic/logic.json');
    $logic_array = json_decode($logic, true);
    unset($logic);
    if (!isset($logic_array[$action])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        foreach ($logic_array[$action] as $action) {
            $actions[] = self::parseActionType($action);
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

and then my array ($data) is forming here

```
public static function parseActionType($actions)
{
    $data = array();
    foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'goto': {
       $goto_actions = self::goToAction($action);
       foreach ($goto_actions as $goto_action) {
                    $data[]= $goto_action;
                }
         } break;
       ....
        }
     }
```

so these functions can call each other, and there can be recursion, and as I understood when this happens, this code `$data[] = $goto_action` puts all of received actions in one element, but I need to put each `$goto_action` in differend element of `$data` array

Comment: your second example is still a multidimensional array. Can you confirm that this is the result that you want? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: From where have you got `[text] => 1`?

Comment: Until you can post an input array (and expected result) where @KrisRoofe 's answer doesn't work, your question is Unclear.   I have voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` to traverse all the value. **[live demo](https://eval.in/923252)**

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use(&$result){
    $result[] = [$k => $v];
});
```

Comment: without `use`: `$c= []; array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k, $c) { $c[0][] = [$k => $v];}, [&$c]); print_r($c);`

Comment: it only removed 1 dimension, but array is still not like i need

Comment: @ИгорьБыстревский， check the demo. It only keep the innermost.

Comment: @ИгорьБыстревский You also can refer to the manual of `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: @KrisRoofe , yea, but it seems like its not gonna work in my situation, can you read update of question, please?

Comment: @ИгорьБыстревский I cannot fully understand the content you updated. Can you show your json content, and your expected output.

Comment: @KrisRoofe heres my JSON https://pastebin.com/AUjRswsP, and here is the code that im using https://pastebin.com/Pn6GeFa0 , i am expecting array that specified in question, but got this https://pastebin.com/iJn2cyyP

Comment: @KrisRoofe and i am calling all this stuff by `goToAction("Переходы");` I understand why its not working, but dont know how to make it work(

Comment: @ИгорьБыстревский use `array_walk_recursive` outside the foreachloop in your `parseActionType` before `return $data;`

Comment: @KrisRoofe well, there may be cases where i need many dimensions arrays, like this https://pastebin.com/WEvSerg2

Comment: @KrisRoofe i've had thoughts that i need use this function for each `$data` element whisch does not contain textual key; Example:`[0]=>Array('text'=>1)` - no need to use it, `[1]=>Array(0=>Array(...))` - need to use, but i dont know how to check if array contains textual key